# Main XUL window that will have blocked resize

Tags: resize, window, xul

I'm looking for a way to block user from resizing main window in XUL app with no luck. 
I want to have window that won't be resizable. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

If someone will look for it. 
in prefs.js in preferences
paste this:  pref("toolkit.defaultChromeFeatures", "chrome,resizable=no,dialog=no");